# Do surjections exist which are not submersions on a set of measure non-zero.

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Let $f: M \to N$ be a smooth maps between smooth manifolds. Then $f$ is a submersion (by definition) if its differential is also surjective. Now suppose $f$ is surjective. Is it possible that the surjective map $f$ fails to be a submersion on a set in $N$ of measure non-zero? If so, what is such a map?

Suppose the manifolds $M$ and $N$ are non-compact. Does this change the previous answer?

Thanks!

Comment: Sard's theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Sard's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard%27s_theorem)

Answer (score 2):

If you relax the smoothness assumption, you can construct a surjection $f:\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\to\mathbb{R}^n$, $n\geq 2$ of class $C^1$ such that ${\rm rank}\, Df\leq 1$ everywhere, see:

**R. Kaufman,** 
[A singular map of a cube onto a square](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214435238).
*J. Differential Geom.* 14 (1979), no. 4, 593–594 (1981). ([MathSciNet review](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=MR&s1=600614&loc=fromreflist).)